How to use "income distribution" and "age distribution"
I have problem using prepositions with "distribution". Are all these options correct? Are "income distribution" and "age distribution" both countable? Maybe in the first sentence, I should use "the income distribution" because it's countable?

The charts show income distribution among/across U.S households. (Does "of" or "for" work?)


The charts show age distributions of/in Yemen and Italy.


The charts show age distributions of the populations of Yemen and
Italy.

I wrote them.

The prepositions you need depend on their object, not the distribution that precedes it. I'd use across or of U.S. households, in Yemen and Italy, and of the populations.

Thank you both. What about the countability? The dictionary says it can be countable or uncountable. I think "distribution" should be used countably in the last two sentences because there are two countries. What about the first sentence? Should "distribution" be used countably or uncountably there?

@Astralbee To my mind there are "clear areas of concern," which eliminates the proofreading concern, and the disparate questions are related enough to "count" as one to my mind. But I agree that it would be helpful to explain more.

income distribution of or for U.S households. Otherwise, in a country. In economics, distribution in this context is singular.

The "Yemen and Italy" examples are using the word in a slightly different way.
Let's take a step back from the statistics context of these usages and just look at the verb form "distribute." It takes certain pronouns; you might "distribute to" or "distribute among" or even "distribute across".  The biggest point is that your distribution has recipients. You are handing something out, and something or someone is receiving it. "The king distributed the gold among the peasants." But if you "distribute the gold of the peasants," we no longer have specified the recipients; instead we've shifted the topic totally to talk about where the gold came from (taxes?). And if you "distribute the gold for the peasants," then perhaps we mean "the gold set aside for the peasants," in which case it's just a coincidence that they're also recipients, or "the king did the peasants' work for them."
The first and third examples name the recipients: "U.S. households" or "the populations." And so either "among" or "across" would be great choices. But in the second example, "age" is not being distributed directly "across" Yemen and Italy; rather, they each have their own "distributions." It is leaving out the obvious recipient, "the population," because the statistical context presumably makes it clear. So sure, "of" or "in" could be good choices, though "across" could work too.

Thank you very much for your professional answer. What about its countability? The dictionary says it can be countable or uncountable. So "income distribution (uncountable) across US households" and "the income distribution (countable) across US households" are both correct?

@newbieforever I'd say it's countable only in these statistical contexts, in which "a distribution" is a familiar entity. "Here's the age distribution for Italy! Here's the income distribution for Yemen! Here are all those distributions on a single graph." But the king's distribution of gold is not countable. I would err on the side of not using them countably; I don't think that would ever be objectionable.

@newbieforever Note, "the income distribution across US households": adding "the" didn't make it countable. It just means "the distribution of income." Now, in statistics, we often speak of distribution curves, and these I think would be countable, since we're speaking of an actual measurement.

@newbieforever Also for the record I haven't actually studied statistics!

Got it, thank you very much!
